# Replace words in NSMutableString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I make a syntax highlighter and I need to replace all occurrences of special words with this word in tags. For example i had:

> @"int main{ bla bla; float=0; bla bla;"

and want to get

> @"<\FONT COLOR=FF00FF>int<\FONT> main{ bla bla; <\FONT COLOR=FF00FF>float<\FONT>=0;" etc.

(had to put \ before FONT).
I have specialwords array, have this text in html (floated with it, i got it from UITextView contentAsHTMLString ) and want just to put color tags. How to?

Tried stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString but

> pr<\FONT COLOR=FF00FF>int<\FONT>f()

is not what i want.

Trying regexkitlite.
[editString replaceOccurrencesOfRegex:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[^a-zA-z]%@[^a-zA-z]",specialString] withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$0%@$1",specialString]  range:NSMakeRange(0, [editString length])];

creates exception (index out of bounds... O_O wtf?) and if i remove $0 and $1 from "withString" it will not replace "int" but " int " (whatever was near the int word too).

Comment: If you really want a syntax highlighter for arbitrary code-samples (do you only cover C btw?) neither simple replace nor regex will get you there - think e.g. `s=" int ";`, escaped linebreaks, typedefs, ... I'd either search for existing highlighters or use an existing parser (e.g. the API of clang).

Answer (score 0):

First apply color to the "int" occurrences:

```
NSString *initialString = @"int main{ bla bla; float=0; bla bla;";    
NSString *stringWithColorInt = [initialString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"int" withString:@"<FONT COLOR=FF00FF>int<\FONT>" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSRange(0,[initialString length])];
```

Then to the "float" occurrences:

```
NSString *stringWithColorFloat = [stringWithColorInt stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"float" withString:@"<FONT COLOR=FF00FF>float<\FONT>" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSRange(0,[stringWithColorInt length])];
```

Comment: I have a huge string with code + html tags. stringByRaplacing replaces all "int"'s, including inside words, like printf.

Comment: NSLiteralSearch is not helping. Still i have highlighted int in printf :(  What i'm trying to say is that stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"int" withString:@"_int_" makes  pr_int_f .